# What parts of the InSight lander are missing between these two photos?

Tags: identify-this-object, insight

The below photo is of the Mars InSight lander shortly after landing, and [one final time before power-down](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA25287) (note the dust on the solar panels)

[image: Insight before and after]

There are three things noticeably missing in the latter photo. What are they?

1. Silver dome
2. Reddish hexagonal housing
3. Black arm just to the left of the silver dome

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the image are the two surface deployable science instruments: [SEIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_Experiment_for_Interior_Structure) and [HP³](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_Flow_and_Physical_Properties_Package).

The "*reddish hexagonal housing*" is the seismometer (SEIS). It is then covered by the "*silver dome*" which is the SEIS Wind and Thermal Shield. Finally the "*black arm*" is not an arm at all (the camera that took these panorama images is on InSight's arm), but the Heat Flow and Physical Properties Package (HP³) instrument.

Keep in mind that the constructed panorama warps the images some bit.

Here are animations of the instruments' deployments:

[image: SEIS deployment]

[image: SEIS shield]

[image: hp3 deployment]

(Source: [NASA’s ‘Cyber Monday’ Mars Landing to Deliver Science Firsts](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2018/11/15/nasas-cyber-monday-mars-landing-to-deliver-science-firsts/))

Comment: I've asked a followup question here https://space.stackexchange.com/q/59332/6944